# fprintf to write into buffer the first k chars

Tags: c, buffer, stdin

I'm given a path to a file which I should modify, whether add the data into the file, or to override the data in the file.txt.

I am also given a limit, if there are 100 chars in the string pointed by data, and the limit is 10, then fprintf should write only the first 10 characters.

It seems fprintf doesn't take such a parameter (limit).
Could someone please suggest a way for me to solve this ?
Thanks in advance!

```
void my_write (char* path, int bytes_number, char* flag, char* data, int sockfd)
{
    FILE* fp;
    int n, i;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (!strcmp(flag, "override"))
    {
        fp = fopen(path, "w+"); /* Open file with flag 'w' to override data */
        if (fp == NULL) /* File doesn't exist, invalid path*/
            write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        i = fprintf (fp, "%s\n", data);
        if (i < 0)
            write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        else
            write (sockfd, "Write Success", strlen("Write Success"));
    }
    rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems fprintf doesn't take such a parameter (limit).

You can specify a width and precision for strings in `printf`. The precision, given after a period, truncates the string if it is longer:

```
printf("%.5s\n", data);
```

will print at most five characters of `data`.

You can make the widths and precisions variable by specifying an asterisk. Then `printf` expects an integer parameter for each star before the actzual (string) argument:

```
printf("%.*s\n", k, data);
```

Note that the widths and precisions must be of type `int`. If necessary, cast the parameter:

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int) k, data);      // k is size_t, say
```

Comment: I am using fprintf to write the data in a .txt file
I edit the post with the whole code.

I will try to use this on fprintf as well.

Comment: The formats are the same for all `*printf` functions, of course. The only difference between `fprintf`, `sprintf` and `printf` is the "sink", i.e. where the formatted string is written to.

Answer (score 0):

Use fwrite() instead of fprintf()

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), k, fp);
```

where k is your limit parameter